# undefined module when file in subfolder

Tags: requirejs

I can't load dependent module `user` from different directory.

Files:

```
\index.html
\js\require.js
\js\main.js
\js\model\user.js
\js\model\post.js
```

**\index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

**\js\main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        model: 'model'
    }
});

require(['model/user'], function (user) {
    user.doAlert();
});
```

**\js\model\user.js**

```
define('user', function () {
    return {
        doAlert: function() {
            alert('done');
        }
    };
});
```

When program goes to line `user.doAlert()` I have an exception in console **TypeError: user.doAlert is not a function**. I debugged that `user` is undefined in this moment. But there is no other message from requirejs. And file is loaded correctly (as I can see in network monitor).

I tried change definition of `user` module to

```
define('model/user', function () {
```

but no success.

Questions

1. How should I fix it to work?
2. There is another model `post` - the
   user should depend on it. How to add this dependency (in context of
   files location)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrong define a model

```
define(function () {
    return {
        doAlert: function() {
            alert('done');
        }
    };
});
```

or simpler:

```
define({
    doAlert: function() {
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

if You need dependency, then:

```
define(['path/to/module'], function (module) {
    return {
        doAlert: function() {
            alert('done');
        }
    };
});
```